# Oauth2, client_credentials, and scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I've been using Oauth2 for quite some time as a developer but still feel at times I need to go back to the basics. I have a general question around this topic, specifically when it comes to using scopes.

As I understand, scopes are a kind of filter that can be applied to certain APIs and the bearer token is required to possess any scope the API requires.  In that sense, they offer an extra 'layer' of protection after the token itself. However, what I would like some feedback on is how best to protect an API that requires scopes. If a consumer obtains a valid bearer token from the issuer and discovers what scope is required for a service, what's the best way to prevent them from making a POST using a token obtained through client_credentials, for example, on a restricted resource?

I believe I know a few solutions: require some sort of user token as well and further lock down resources via a authorization in your business logic (e.g. customers can only modify their own data). Another option might be to require api registration and an approval workflow so only 'approved' clients can invoke a service. Similar to how Akana and other API Gateway products operate. But are there other things I'm missing? Are Scopes really meant to serve as an authorization mechanism at all, or am I misinterpreting their real purpose, because to me they don't seem like they offer much.

Thanks for feedback in advance.

Comment: Your wording is confusing: *If a consumer obtains a valid bearer token from the issuer and discovers what scope is required for a service, what's the best way to prevent them from making a POST using a token obtained through client_credentials, for example, on a restricted resource?* With "issuer" you mean authorization server, right? With "consumer" you mean client, right? The client doesn't discover which scope is required, the resource owner can grant a scope. And you configure the scope in your resource server, so only tokens with the right token can access the resource.

Comment: *I believe I know a few solutions: require some sort of user token as well and further lock down resources via a authorization in your business logic* Why? The access token contains contains the scope and the resource server checks the scope.

Comment: AFAIK the main feature of scope is that the client has not all rights of the resource owner, although the client call the resource server in behalf of the resource owner.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Yes - 'issuer' I meant authorization server. And 'consumer' I meant client.   I understand what you are saying about the client not having all rights and the resource server checks the scope. For example, when using an authorization code as in a normal web app flow, the user sees a page where they may see checkboxes with scopes and ask the user to acknowledge that they are giving this level of access. However, in a server-to-server scenario using client_credentials, that step of user involvement is missing.   Your feedback was helpful and appreciated.